# Magento 2- How to move custom options after cart button?

Tags: magento2, layout, attributes, custom-options, addtocart

I want to move custom options below Add to Cart button and also want to move short description within form tag.How can I achieve this?

Also I want to know why my custom php code not working in addtocart phtml file?
Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**case 1:** 
Assume that you are using a custom theme name "Vendor_yourtheme".

Update the file ***YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/design/frontend/Vendor/yourtheme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml***  as below

File : **catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">    
    <body>        
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.form.options">
            <move element="product.info.options" destination="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom"  />
        </referenceBlock>                 
        <move element="product.info" destination="product.info.main" before="product.info.addtocart"/>                       
    </body>
</page>
```

**Case 2:** Assume that you are using a custom extension name Company_MyModule to update product view detail page layout.

Update the file ***YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/code/Company/MyMyModule/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml*** with below below

File : **catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">    
    <body>        
        <<referenceBlock name="product.info.form.options">
            <move element="product.info.options" destination="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom"  />
        </referenceBlock>                 
        <move element="product.info" destination="product.info.main" before="product.info.addtocart"/>                       
    </body>
</page>
```

Please clear Mageto  cache to view the updated layout changes in front end.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.I'll try this and come back to you.

Comment: Thanks man. It helps me  to rearrange my product page layout.

Comment: Can you also help to show related product in a thumbnail slider?

Comment: @ShoaibSaleem  My pleasure.

Comment: @ShoaibSaleem. yes relates product can be shown in thumbnail slider.
Shall I add another answer or you will post a separate question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86442/discussion-between-shoaib-saleem-and-pritam-info-24).

Comment: For moving social link like add to compare and wish list below add to cart <move element="product.info.social" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.main"/>