# How to move Custom Options after product Description Tab in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I want to move product custom option after the description tab section .Can any one suggest me ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this Solution :-

Update the file YOUR-MAGENTO-**`ROOT/app/design/frontend/Vendor/yourtheme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`** as below

File : **`catalog_product_view.xml`**

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.form.options">
            <move element="product.info.options" destination="product.info.description"  />
</referenceBlock>
```

Check for more information :-

**[Magento 2- How to move custom options after cart button?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/251722/magento-2-how-to-move-custom-options-after-cart-button)**

**`THANKS.`**